# If a computer has 22gb ssd that is "100% free" ... what is it really doing?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, ssd

I am a Windows newbie, and just ran into a computer with 22GB SSD drive and a 1TB normal hard drive.  The SSD drive according to diskmgmt.msc says its space is 100% free.  What does this mean?  Also, if one wanted to dual boot Ubuntu on a machine like this, are there any extra considerations that would need to be taken?

Comment: this small SSD is normally used as Cache for the normal HDD.

Answer (score 0):

What that means depends on whether and how the SSD is partitioned. If the SSD is one big partition "100% free" would mean it's currently unused. However it's much more likely that the SSD contains at least two partitions, one being Windows's system partition and the other being the remaining 22GB. In that case "100% free" simply means that the 22GB *besides* Windows's system partition on the SSD are free. *This is just an assumption of course.*

For dual booting Ubuntu on this machine it would be wise to install it the same way the already existing Windows installation was set up: Put the system partition on the remaining 22GB on the SSD, and put its other partition(s) on the 1TB HDD. This means you will have to install your Ubuntu in a way that allows you to create partitions for it and tell it what to put on what partition.

Especially with an SSD this small this type of setup is optimal since system partitions on SSDs massively speed up booting, whereas most other applications can't profit as much from an SSD. Really the only non-system applications that *really* profit from SSDs are some overly disk-access-heavy games and video-editing software in very specific cases. Both of those only ever apply if you already have a very high-end CPU/GPU or configure them badly (saving uncompressed video at high resolutions for example).

Comment: Hmm.  It's listed as a primary partition in diskmgmt.msc, and no file system is currently on it.  Also, it is not using this for booting.  There is a 300 mb EFI partition on the main drive for that.  I heard that it might be using the drive for caching reads/writes as a staging area, but I cannot confirm this.

Comment: Oh, also, I don't think the drive is mounted.  It doesn't show up in the file browser.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then my first assumption is probably wrong. If it's not mounted then caching seems the only likely use. Even if that's the case moving the 300MB EFI to the SSD would give the system a HUGE booting speed boost at almost no cost (300MB less caching space on 22GB is very little).